# Two Way IP Tunneling

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi, home-networking

Hello Networking Experts

I have been doing computer networks since before Ethernet existed, so I am pretty good at networks, routers, switches, VPN serves etc. But I am not an expert on all of it.

I would like to connect the network at my house to the network at my brother's house. I have mine set up as 192.168.2.0/24 and he is set up as 192.168.1.0/24, so we already have our networks unique so they can be routed easily with no overlap of IP numbers.

I currently have a Wireguard VPN server running on a Raspberry Pi at my house and he can connect into that just fine and get to all of the computers at my house from the ONE computer that he has Wireguard installed on. I also have OpenVPN running on the same Raspberry PI, but am currently not using it because Wireguard works just fine. We used OpenVPN before we discovered WireGuard.

I would like to set up a two way IP tunnel using either OpenVPN, Wiregaurd, iptables, a combination of the above, or even a completely different solution.

We would have dedicated Raspberry PIs on each end handling this. Our Network providers make it easy to have port forwarding to devices which is how the VPN server works.

The goal is that either one of us can get to any computer / device at the other location from any computer at our location.

My brother has a large observatory. with three telescopes, 3 other cameras, with a total of about a dozen Raspberry PIs running the observatory and telescope. I have 6 Raspberry Pis and two large SQL database servers. He uses the SQL server from his house all the time.

See
http://www.skychariot.com/dome.html for the observatory and
and see
http://www.skychariot.com/gaia.html for one of the many things I am running on the SQL database server.

Any help would be appreciated.  I have looked and looked and have not found a good description of how to do this.

Once I get it done and working, I will document it, put it up on my server and make the procedure available to other people wanting to do this.

Thanks

Keith Sproul
(ksproul@skychariot.com)

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about these things but you never know what people don't know so I'll chime in that an SSH tunnel is a secure way to send data back and forth. You'll want to make sure the database machine isn't set up to ignore database requests from the gateway. On a Mac there was a plugin required in my instance that interfaced with the keychain.

I found lots of info once I knew an SSH tunnel was what I needed. Handy gadgets!

With that out of the way (and pardon me if that was painfully obvious for someone that knows their networking) when you say:

*The goal is that either one of us can get to any computer / device at the other location from any computer at our location.*

it sounds like you need something more robust.

For total control of the computers at your brothers from any computer or mobile device take a look at

[Parallels Access](https://www.parallels.com/products/access/?)

it hid under my nose while I looked at more complicated solutions but is now working wonderfully, giving full access to up to 5 computers for $20 a year.

It's fast, super easy to set up, and unobtrusive for a local user on the machine.

It's been working flawlessly so far. I'm seeing very little lag, almost none. It's like you're sitting at the remote machine and it's pretty cool having whichever computer you want to connect to running on an iPad.

The connection is SSL and 256 bit AES, no data, including the password, is decrypted or stored on Parallel's servers.

I don't know what I don't know, but I was pleasantly surprised at how well it works and how reasonable the pricing is. If you can connect to the devices from the computers on site perhaps this could work.

I hope this helps!

BTW, super cool stuff you've got going on !!

Answer (score 0):

The tunnel is already bidirectional from the beginning; there really is nothing more to it compared to any other connection between two routers (the Pi's being the routers), with the "AllowedIPs=" packet filter in WireGuard being the only difference that matters (compared to e.g. an Ethernet or PPP connection).

1. On your network's main gateway, route 192.168.1.0/24 via your Pi's LAN address (i.e. via the tunnel gateway). On the friend's LAN gateway, the opposite route to 192.168.2.0/24 via their Pi needs to be added.
2. On both tunnel endpoints, likewise route 192.168.1.0/24 or 192.168.2.0/24 through the actual tunnel interface (wg0). If you're using wg-quick, it'll do this automatically based on AllowedIPs.
3. Finally, make sure iptables "forward" rules as well as WireGuard "AllowedIPs=" permit packets from one network to another and back, i.e. the "friend" peer entry on your side needs to allow packets *from* 192.168.1.0/24 and vice versa.

(You should also disable any "masquerade" iptables NAT rules that are currently on the Pi, or at least make sure to skip them for local addresses – the route you have makes masquerading unnecessary.)